# View Deleted Questions privilege does not work on StackExchange app

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app

I recently tried to view [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906649/how-to-print-a-char-array-in-c-with-printf) on the Android app, and got the following error.

```
This question is not available, it may have been deleted.
```

I am not sure whether it was a deliberate choice to not allow us to execute the 10K privilege of viewing deleted questions on the Android app, but if it is not, I'd like to make that a feature request.

Comment: The Android App uses the API, which does not expose deleted posts to anyone.

Comment: @animuson, Do you happen to know if it was a deliberate design decision in the API or just omitted for simplicity?